# Send email with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I can't send email with symfony2

**app/config/config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   mymail@gmail.com
    password:   mypassword
```

**src/Ga/CmsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
emailing:
  pattern: /emailing
  defaults: { _controller: "GaCmsBundle:main:emailing" }
```

**src/Ga/CmsBundle/Controller/mainController.php**

```
public function emailingAction()
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('anothermail@yahoo.com')
        ->setBody('mahdi musawie');
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return new response("mahdi");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to set a port (this one was 465 for google apps) or use transport: gmail

this one works fine for me: (i use google apps)

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: xxx@my-domain.com
mailer_password: xxx
mailer_port: 465
```